# Radio button change events and improving similar functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm looking for a smarter way to reuse functions with a similar purpose.  For example I would want to change different radio buttons that toggle a hide class on different divs.

[JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/338zr1a7/1/)

How would you mathe JQuery to a reusable function,

```
<form>
    <label>Enable One</label>
    <input type="radio" name="one" value="yes" checked class="eOne">Yes
    <input type="radio" name="one" value="no" class="enBg">No</form>
<form>
    <label>Enable Two</label>
    <input type="radio" name="two" value="yes" checked class="eTwo">Yes
    <input type="radio" name="two" value="no" class="enBrand">No</form>
<form>
    <label>Enable Three</label>
    <input type="radio" name="three" value="yes" checked class="eThree">Yes
    <input type="radio" name="three" value="no" class="enS">No</form>
<div class="one"></div>
<div class="two"></div>
<div class="three"></div>

div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
.one {
    background: red;
}
.two {
    background: green;
}
.three {
    background: blue;
}
.hide {
    display: none;
}

$(".eOne").change(function () {
    $('.one').toggleClass("hide");
});

$(".eTwo").change(function () {
    $('.two').toggleClass("hide");
});

$(".eThree").change(function () {
    $('.three').toggleClass("hide");
});
```

Also, for some reason, in the demo (but not in my live version) the change function doesn't toggle the class unless I click no and then yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use classes for your html:

```
<form>
    <label>Enable One</label>
    <input type="radio" name="one" value="yes" class="one" checked />Yes
    <input type="radio" name="one" value="no" class="one" />No
</form>
<form>
    <label>Enable Two</label>
    <input type="radio" name="two" value="yes" class="two" checked />Yes
    <input type="radio" name="two" value="no" class="two" />No
</form>
<div class="one"></div>
<div class="two"></div>
```

write functions for your javascript:

```
/*
 * Bind a change event handler to a radio-input
 * @param cls - selector string to input AND to-change div
 */
function bindChangeHandler(cls) {
    $('input.' + cls).change(function () {
        var element = $(this),// get Input element
            name = element.val(), // get Input element name
            is_checked = element.prop('checked'); // get state of radio box

        // return if a deselect triggered the event (may be unnecessary)
        if (!is_checked) return;

        // change class of div-box according to checked radio-box 
        if  (name == 'yes') {
            $('div.' + cls).removeClass('hide');
        } else {
            $('div.' + cls).addClass('hide');
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    bindChangeHandler('one');
    bindChangeHandler('two');
});
```

Comment: I added a bit of documentation. Throw in some `console.log` instructions to inspect variables for better understanding of the machanics.

Comment: Curious, I tried this with Checkboxes instead of radio buttons, but it didn't work.  What would the difference be?

Answer (score 2):

HTML

```
<form>
    <label>Enable One</label>
    <input type="radio" name="one" value="yes" class="eOne" checked>Yes
    <input type="radio" name="one" value="no" class="enBg">No
    <br /><label>Enable Two</label>
    <input type="radio" name="two" value="yes" checked class="eTwo">Yes
    <input type="radio" name="two" value="no" class="enBrand">No
    <br /><label>Enable Three</label>
    <input type="radio" name="three" value="yes" checked class="eThree">Yes
    <input type="radio" name="three" value="no" class="enS">No
</form>
    <div class="one"></div>
    <div class="two"></div>
    <div class="three"></div>
```

I haven't changed any of your CSS but changed your Javascript code. Have a look at this.There is no need to use the class .hideclass as we have already an inbuilt method for this. the toggle() method. if you want it to hide as soon as you click the radio button then just change all the toggle() to toggle(50). This change will hide the div boxes in just 50 milli seconds.

```
$("input[name='one']").change(function(){
    $(".one").toggle();//add a number in toggle method to have a small animation effect :)
});
$("input[name='two']").change(function(){
    $(".two").toggle();
});
$("input[name='three']").change(function(){
    $(".three").toggle();
});
```

I have also updated the code on js fiddle. May be this is helpful for you :)

Comment: This is works great, thanks for taking the time to answer.  My question would be, is there a more efficient way to handle this?  Let's say I have 10+ options on one page, I would imagine writing a desperate function for each is quite inefficient.

Answer (score 1):

I like [cbergmiller](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30284408/5651119)'s answer. Here is the same rewritten with a callback allowing a more general use:

```
function hide(cls, name) {
    // change class of div-box according to checked radio-box 
    if  (name == 'yes') {
        $('div.' + cls).removeClass('hide');
    } else {
        $('div.' + cls).addClass('hide');
    }
}

/*
 * Bind a change event handler to a radio-input
 * @param cls - selector string to input AND to-change div
 */
function bindChangeHandler(cls, callback) {
    $('input.' + cls).change(function () {
        var element = $(this),// get Input element
            name = element.val(); // get Input element name
        callback(cls, name);
    });
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    bindChangeHandler('one', hide);
    bindChangeHandler('two', hide);
});
```